# Where on an entire column Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

It does not take the exact date from me in the WHERE clause "2020-06-18". It shows me all the dates ???

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM   (SELECT a.cheval, 
               a.numero, 
               a.jour, 
               a.hippo, 
               a.jockey, 
               a.entraineur, 
               a.typec, 
               a.partant, 
               a.dist, 
               a.cl, 
               b.tempscourse, 
               a.poidmont, 
               a.vha 
        FROM   p_mu.cachedate AS a 
               INNER JOIN p_mu.caractrap AS b 
                       ON a.comp = b.comp) t 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   p_mu.cheval 
               WHERE  cheval = t.cheval)
IN (select 1 From p_mu.cachedate where jour = "2020-06-18");
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output for that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic that you seem to want is:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM p_mu.cheval c
              WHERE c.cheval = t.cheval
             ) AND
      t.jour = '2020-06-18';
```

That said, your query is looking for the result of the `exists` in the subquery.  The `exists` returns `0` or `1` -- the equivalent of "false" and "true".  The subquery is only returning `1`.  So, when the `exists` is true, then all rows are returned -- there is no filtering because the only condition is always true.